# Two divergent sequences like $\{x_k\},\{y_k\}$ such that $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}|y_k-x_k|=0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, examples-counterexamples

A sequence with a limit that is a real number is called a convergent sequence.

A sequence which does not converge is said to be divergent.

Find two divergent sequences like $\{x_k\},\{y_k\}$ such that $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}|y_k-x_k|=0$  .

**Notice that we know $\forall k \in \mathbb N \space 0 \lt |y_k-x_k|$**

Note ( For those who ask about my try ) : There is nothing to try! If my try was successful, I wouldn't be asking this question.

Comment: What's wrong with $x_k=y_k=k$?

Comment: @Sloan this is the assumption of the question ... they shouldn't be equal

Comment: @Sloan i wrote that their difference is more than zero ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
x_n=(-1)^n+\frac1n\quad\text{and}\quad y_n=(-1)^n.
$$

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear to me why there is "nothing to try"; you can certainly try to think of two divergent sequences that have a minor (or no) difference. 
For example, take $x_k=y_k=k$, or less trivially, $x_k=k$ and $y_k=k+\frac1k$